# Linear Transformation On Basis

Tags: linear-algebra

What a Linear Transformation does on a basis? if the Linear Transformation is 1-1 and onto so every element of the basis goes to element of the basis of the other vector space? and what if it is not 1-1 and onto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- An injective linear transformation transforms a basis to a linear independent set of vectors.
- A surjective linear transformation transforms a basis to set of vectors that spans the linear space
- A bijective linear transformation transforms a basis to a basis.

Comment: 1 and 2 are true if $Dim(V) \neq Dim(W)$

Answer (score 1):

If it's not $1-1$ then basis elements need not go to basis elements- example $T(x)=0$ for all $x \in V$.

Same comment and example will work if $T$ is not onto.

Now, if $T$ is $1-1$ but not onto then the image of the basis vectors will be linearly independent (the proof is simple) but they won't be a basis. Example: $T: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ by $T(x)=(x,0).$

If $T$ is onto but not $1-1$ then basis vectors go to a spanning set- but are not linearly independent (proof is simple again). Example $T: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $T((x,y))=(x,0).$

Comment: why $T: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ by $T(x)=(x,0).$ is linearly independent?

Comment: There is only $1$basis vector of $\mathbb{R}$. It gets sent to a non zero vector in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and a single non-zero vector is l.ind by definition.

Comment: where can I find proofs?
Thanks